# A new column in pandas which value depends on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I have an example data as:

```
datetime             col1    col2    col3
2021-04-10 01:00:00    25.    50.     50
2021-04-10 02:00:00.   25.    50.     50
2021-04-10 03:00:00.   25.    100.    50
2021-04-10 04:00:00    50.     50.    100
2021-04-10 05:00:00.   100.    100.   100
```

I want to create a new column called state, which returns col1 value if col2 and col3 values are  less than or equal to 50 otherwise returns the max value between col1,column2 and column3.

The expected output is as shown below:

```
datetime             col1    col2    col3. state
2021-04-10 01:00:00    25.    50.     50.   25
2021-04-10 02:00:00.   25.    50.     50.   25
2021-04-10 03:00:00.   25.    100.    50.   100
2021-04-10 04:00:00    50.     50.    100.  100
2021-04-10 05:00:00.   100.    100.   100.  100
```

Comment: What do you mean " the mean of max value"? The mean of a single value would just be the max value no?

Comment: I meant the max value.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To improve upon other answer, I would use [pandas apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for iterating over rows and calculating new column.

```py
def calc_new_col(row):
   if row['col2'] <= 50 & row['col3'] <= 50:
        return row['col1']
    else:
        return max(row['col1'], row['col2'], row['col3'])

df["state"] = df.apply(calc_new_col, axis=1)
# axis=1 makes sure that function is applied to each row

print(df)
            datetime  col1  col2  col3  state
2021-04-10  01:00:00    25    50    50     25
2021-04-10  02:00:00    25    50    50     25
2021-04-10  03:00:00    25   100    50    100
2021-04-10  04:00:00    50    50   100    100
2021-04-10  05:00:00   100   100   100    100
```

`apply` helps the code to be cleaner and more reusable.

Comment: this is by far the most pythonic and also logical way. The `apply` statement on `row` avoids looping.

Answer (score 4):

```
# Create a mask:

# Create a mask for the basic condition
mask1 = ((df['col2'] <= 50) & (df['col3'] <= 50))

# Use loc to select rows where condition is met and input the df['col1'] value in state
df.loc[mask1, 'state'] = df['col1']

# Check for rows where condition is not met ~ does that, input the mean in state.
df.loc[~mask1, 'state'] = (df['col1'] + df['col2'] + df['col3'])/3
```

Comment: This answer highlights how `vectorized` calculations can be done on dataframes.

Comment: It does not appear that indexes 2-4 match the expected output.

Comment: @HenryEcker Contradiction in the question asked and output given in the question. I have done the best I could based on the info.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the dataframe's rows and check the condition

```
values = []

for ind, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['col2'] <= 50 & row['col3'] <= 50:
        values.append(row['col1'])
    else:
        values.append(max(row['col1'], row['col2'], row['col3']))

df['state'] = values

print(df)
            datetime  col1  col2  col3  state
2021-04-10  01:00:00    25    50    50     25
2021-04-10  02:00:00    25    50    50     25
2021-04-10  03:00:00    25   100    50    100
2021-04-10  04:00:00    50    50   100    100
2021-04-10  05:00:00   100   100   100    100
```

Answer (score 0):

An option using [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy.where):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': {0: '2021-04-10 01:00:00', 1: '2021-04-10 02:00:00',
                                2: '2021-04-10 03:00:00', 3: '2021-04-10 04:00:00',
                                4: '2021-04-10 05:00:00'},
                   'col1': {0: 25.0, 1: 25.0, 2: 25.0, 3: 50.0, 4: 100.0},
                   'col2': {0: 50.0, 1: 50.0, 2: 100.0, 3: 50.0, 4: 100.0},
                   'col3': {0: 50, 1: 50, 2: 50, 3: 100, 4: 100}})

df['state'] = np.where((df['col2'] <= 50) & (df['col3'] <= 50), df.col1, df.max(axis=1))

print(df)
```

Output:

```
           datetime  col1  col2  col3  state
2021-04-10 01:00:00  25.0  50.0    50   25.0
2021-04-10 02:00:00  25.0  50.0    50   25.0
2021-04-10 03:00:00  25.0 100.0    50  100.0
2021-04-10 04:00:00  50.0  50.0   100  100.0
2021-04-10 05:00:00 100.0 100.0   100  100.0
```